# Worklight application loops by wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm challenges

Tags: iphone, ibm-mobilefirst

My application with authentication is based on the sample code for Module 21. It is running on Android and PC-browser well. I have added an iPhone Environment and tested it on Xcode and Simulator then strange loop has occurred.

By my investigation, first call to adapter procedure enters loop. It seems caused by challenges response from adapter.
I have taken TCP trace with eclipse as following.

<request>

**adapter=AdapterName&procedure=ProcedureName&parameters=xxxxxx&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.19480942375957966**

<response>

**/*-secure-
{"challenges":{"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"token":"lsfssroob823c30493g709st01"}}}*/**

This occurs only on iPhone/iPad Simulator ( not on Android nor PC browser).

I had tried to add and remove some elements on authenticationConfig.xml but doesn't effect.

- Worklight 5.0.5.1
- xcode 4.6
- iPhone Simulator iOS 5.0~6.1

How can I solve this ?

Comment: I've been struggling on this problem in this weekend. I tried to construct project from sample code on tutorial which works fine. Replacing code by my project and found the <displayName> on application-descriptor.xml contains KATAKANA (Japanese) character causes this problem only on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your bundleId attribute to the iPhone/iPad element in your application-descriptor.xml?